# Covering of a topological group

Tags: group-theory, topological-groups, covering-spaces

Let $X$ be a topological group with a locally path-connected, path-connected covering $(\tilde{X},p)$. If we fix an $u\in p^{-1}(e)$, we should be able to deduce a unique group structure for $H=\tilde{X}$ such that the identity element is $u$, and $p$ is a morphism of groups.

Up to now, I've been able to use the lifting criterion to deduce the product $$g\,:\,H\times H\longrightarrow H,$$ and I've also shown using the uniqueness of liftings that $g(h,\, u)=h=g(u,\, h)$.

Now, I'm stuck on proving that the operation $g$ is associative and there are inverses. Do you have any hint? I know I should apply uniqueness of liftings but how in those cases?

EDIT: I managed to prove that the $g$ is associative, but I still cannot construct the  right maps for the inverses.

EDIT2: Let $i_G$ be the inversion map for $G$, then we consider the composition $$i_Gp:H\longrightarrow G.$$ The problem should now be if it is possible to lift that map using the lifting criterion. But I cannot see why $(i_G)_*(p_*(\pi_1(H,\, u)))$ should be contained in $p_*(\pi_1(H,\, u))$

Comment: Is your topological group $X$  semi-locally simply connected?

Comment: No. I know that would give an "universal cover", and than you can probably construct directly the product in the cover, but no, I'm looking for an answer without that hypothesis.

Comment: To prove what you want, you can apply the Eckmann-Hilton argument to see that the two multiplications on $\pi_1(X,e)$ coincide

Comment: @Max That was unexpectedly helpful!

Comment: @W4cc0 After lifting the map $i_G p$, how did you show that the lifted map is the inversion map of $H$? I got stuck in this step.